# Iterating through a list with dataclasses, and checking if an element matches the inputted int?

Tags: python, list, loops, nested-lists, python-dataclasses

I"m having a bit of trouble with my code. I'm trying to get the IDs from the list and compare it to an int input. If the int is the same as the ID, it'll print("Yes"). If it doesn't match an ID, it'll print("no"). Problem is, it's printing no for even the numbers that should return yes to..

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Dog:
    ID: int
    name: str


dog_details = [
    Dog(
        ID=1,
        name="Toby"),
    Dog(
        ID=2,
        name="Rex",
    ),
    Dog(
        ID=3,
        name="Sandy",
    ),
    Dog(
        ID=4,
        name="Wanda",
    ),
    Dog(
        ID=5,
        name="Toto",
    ),
]

while True:
    for index in range(len(dog_details)):
        identification = int(input("What ID? "))
        if identification != dog_details:
            print("no")
        elif identification == dog_details:
            print("Yes")
```

I'm toying with variations of:

```
while True:
    for index in range(len(dog_details)):

        identification = int(input("What ID? "))
        if identification != dog_details:
            print("no")
        elif identification == dog_details:
            print("Yes")
```

Problem is, it is saying no for every number inputted.

Comment: print(dog_details) when you compare to identification, print(identification) also . Are they the same?

Comment: dog_details :[Dog(ID=1, name='Toby'), Dog(ID=2, name='Rex'), Dog(ID=3, name='Sandy'), Dog(ID=45, name='Wan'), Dog(ID=450, name='To')]

identification : 2

Comment: Do you know how to access attributes of an object?

Comment: is "[Dog(ID=1, name='Toby')," equal to "1"?

Comment: @Axe319 sorry, I mistyped. Edited!

Comment: @Axe319 I was using dog_details[0].ID to get the ID from the first dog, but I wanted to compare to ALL IDs. I'm not too sure how to actually access them as a whole.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood I see what you are saying there! Seems to be the error. I'll play around and see if I can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dog_details` is a list of `Dog`s; it will never be equal to an `int`.

What I think you might want is:

```
while True:
    for dog in dog_details:
        identification = int(input("What ID? "))
        if identification == dog.ID:
            print(f"Yes, this is {dog.name}")
        else:
            print(f"no, this is {dog}")
```

Note that because you're asking for an ID inside the `for` loop, you're comparing the ID to a specific `dog` in the list.  (I added that `dog` to the `print` statement so that when it says "no" you can see what dog it was comparing your ID to.)  If you want to compare it to *all* the dogs and return the matching one, do:

```
dogs_by_id = {dog.ID: dog for dog in dog_details}
while True:
    identification = int(input("What ID? "))
    if identification in dogs_by_id:
        print(f"Yes: {dogs_by_id[identification].name}")
    else:
        print("no")
```

The first line creates a `dict` that will allow you to look up a dog by its ID.  If you were to do this without a dict, it's more complicated; you need to loop through the entire list each time, something like:

```
while True:
    identification = int(input("What ID? "))
    for dog in dog_details:
        if dog.ID == identification:
            print(f"Yes: {dog.name}")
            break
    else:
        print("no")
```

Comment: That second one seems to have done the trick. It was my first time using dataclasses so the list format was confusing me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You wanted to compare ID against identification.

```
identification = 0
while identification >= 0:
    identification = int(input("What ID? "))
    found_dog = None

    for dog in dog_details:
        if dog.ID == identification:
            found_dog = dog

    if found_dog:
        print("Yes!", found_dog)
    else:
        print("No.")
```

Type -1 or CTRL-C to exit the loop.

Comment: `for... if... found=something` is usually an anti-pattern in python, unless you have very long or complex conditions. It can be reduced to `found_dog = next((dog for dog in dog_details if dog.ID == identification), None)` or even `try/except/else` around `next` without default.

Comment: I try to meet the audience where I find them. The OP is ATM still struggling with indexing versus iteration, so I was hoping to encourage the simple `for x in xs:` idiom in their future writings. The multiline format encourages print() / breakpoint() debugging. I considered a `break` for early exit, so O(N) search becomes 2x faster but still O(N) linear, and chose to reject that complexity as not a good didactic fit. The dict / set solutions here are lovely, supporting repeated O(1) lookups; I just didn't go there. I feel they are perfectly nice solutions.

Comment: Hm, than really makes sense, great! I didn't look from that perspective

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `ID` attribute of the `Dog` class to access the Dog instance's ID (`int`); then you can check for equality, and your program should behave as expected.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Dog:
    ID: int
    name: str

dog_details = [
    Dog(ID=1, name="Toby"),
    Dog(ID=2, name="Rex"),
    Dog(ID=3, name="Sandy"),
    Dog(ID=4, name="Wanda"),
    Dog(ID=5, name="Toto"),
]

dog_ids = set(d.ID for d in dog_details)
while True:
    id_ = int(input("What ID? "))
    if id_ not in dog_ids:
        print('no')
    else:
        print('yes')
        break
```